# FlexSlider sync after adding/removing sliders

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flexslider

I just implemented a slider with thumbnails using FlexSlider and everything works just fine.

When I click one of the thumbnails the slider would move to that slide.

However, after I remove all slides and add new slides the main slider works just fine but the thumbnail navigation does not work. It checked all html codes but the syntax seems to be the same.

Is there any way to sync this again?

Here is my code where I initialize the setting.

```
$('#carousel').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: false,
  slideshow: false,
  itemWidth: 150,
  itemMargin: 5,
  asNavFor: '#slider'
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: false,
  slideshow: false,
  sync: "#carousel"
});
```

And here is where I remove / add slides.

```
while ($('#slider').data('flexslider').count > 0) 
    $('#slider').data('flexslider').removeSlide(0);
while ($('#carousel').data('flexslider').count > 0) 
    $('#carousel').data('flexslider').removeSlide(0);

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/getImage.php",
    data: {idStyle: $('#idStyle').val(), color: a},  
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(response){
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          $('#slider').data('flexslider').addSlide('<li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></li>');
          $('#carousel').data('flexslider').addSlide('<li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></li>');
      }
    }
});

$('#slider').flexslider(0);
$('#carousel').flexslider(0);
```

[image: FlexSlider with carousel]

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to give each `li` indexed id and manually put function on it and it works perfectly fine. I'm posting my code in case someone faces the same issue.

```
$("#flexSlide").on("click", ".carouselInner", function(event){
    var idx = $(this).attr('id');
    idx = parseInt(idx.replace('carouselInner', ''));

    $('#slider').flexslider(idx - 1);
    $('#carousel').flexslider(idx - 1);
});
```